# Auto refresh on editing a post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

On editing a post, a feedback message is shown stating:

> Your edit has been submitted successfully

However, this does not auto-refresh/update the content in question. A pull-to-refresh has to be done to see the *updated* content.

I think that a post should auto-refresh on submitting an edit, if a connection is available.

Version: 0.1.31

Comment: "live refresh" is something else, removing the tag. (I doubt there is web sockets connection in the android app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually supposed to be working so I was confused when I saw this request over the weekend.

It's been fixed and will go out in the app update tonight, version 0.1.34.